# Labels on Prometheus metrics when serving multiple models with Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

We are serving multiple TF models using the standard `tensorflow/serving` docker container. Following the docs, we enabled monitoring by supplying a 'prometheus' config. Metrics are emitted as expected. TFS does label a few metrics in a way that differentiates between the separate models it is serving, for example, it shows the `model_path` on model load attempts and latency:

```
# TYPE :tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_attempt_count counter
:tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_attempt_count{model_path="gs://disco-int-100-mlops/ml-sandbox-101-tagging/servables/models/1598020514",status="success"} 1
:tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_attempt_count{model_path="gs://ml-sandbox-examples/HousingModel/2020-10-05T10:37:56/1",status="success"} 1
# TYPE :tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_latency counter
:tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_latency{model_path="gs://disco-int-100-mlops/ml-sandbox-101-tagging/servables/models/1598020514"} 19274403
:tensorflow:cc:saved_model:load_latency{model_path="gs://ml-sandbox-examples/HousingModel/2020-10-05T10:37:56/1"} 2938076
```

Most other TFS metrics do not have any labels at all. Is it possible to provide additional configuration parameters so the we get, for example, `:tensorflow:core:graph_run_time_usecs_histogram_bucket` metrics labelled for each served model?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the simple answer is "no, there are no additional configuration parameters for the Prometheus metrics config". The code that generates the metrics endpoint output is here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/util/prometheus_exporter.cc

Looks like an opportunity to make a contribution to TFS...